# Debug React-native in Chrome instead of Flipper

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native@0.66.1,

I would like to debug using the chrome console, instead of flipper.

In ios simulator developer menu, I randomly get either
`Open Debugger` (-> opens flipper) or `Debug JS Remotely` (-> opens chrome)

Can I permanently disable flipper and only debug with chrome?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found a way:
disable this block in node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules/RCTDevMenu.mm

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules/RCTDevMenu.mm b/node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules/RCTDevMenu.mm
index 881c3f2..1447e8f 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules/RCTDevMenu.mm
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules/RCTDevMenu.mm
@@ -230,36 +230,7 @@ RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()
                                                }]];
 
   if (!devSettings.isProfilingEnabled) {
-#if RCT_ENABLE_INSPECTOR
-    if (devSettings.isDeviceDebuggingAvailable) {
-      // For on-device debugging we link out to Flipper.
-      // Since we're assuming Flipper is available, also include the DevTools.
-      // Note: For parity with the Android code.
-      [items addObject:[RCTDevMenuItem
-                           buttonItemWithTitleBlock:^NSString * {
-                             return @"Open Debugger";
-                           }
-                           handler:^{
-                             [RCTInspectorDevServerHelper
-                                          openURL:@"flipper://null/Hermesdebuggerrn?device=React%20Native"
-                                    withBundleURL:bundleManager.bundleURL
-                                 withErrorMessage:@"Failed to open Flipper. Please check that Metro is runnning."];
-                           }]];
-
-      [items addObject:[RCTDevMenuItem
-                           buttonItemWithTitleBlock:^NSString * {
-                             return @"Open React DevTools";
-                           }
-                           handler:^{
-                             [RCTInspectorDevServerHelper
-                                          openURL:@"flipper://null/React?device=React%20Native"
-                                    withBundleURL:bundleManager.bundleURL
-                                 withErrorMessage:@"Failed to open Flipper. Please check that Metro is runnning."];
-                           }]];
-    } else if (devSettings.isRemoteDebuggingAvailable) {
-#else
     if (devSettings.isRemoteDebuggingAvailable) {
-#endif
       // For remote debugging, we open up Chrome running the app in a web worker.
       // Note that this requires async communication, which will not work for Turbo Modules.
       [items addObject:[RCTDevMenuItem
```